# Tubeless tyre pressure on 29er wheels?

Tags: 29er, tire

I know that tyre pressure is a pretty subjective thing with many factors coming into play (tyre type, terrain etc.) but would I be able to run lower pressures for the same conditions on a 29er than on a 26er due to the larger tyre footprint?

For example: I typically run my tubeless tyres on a 26er between 2.0-2.3 bar (29-33 psi) would I be able to run the pressure in the 1.8-2.0 bar (26-29 psi) range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read that higher volume tires work better with lower pressure, but for what it's worth, you'd be better off trying it on the trail and seeing for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I ride my tubeless Schwalbe Nobby Nics (27.5'') on around 2 bar in the rear, and 1.8 bar in the front.

The Nobby Nics are fat beasts and so far held up perfectly. With the above setup I get a super comfy ride with a ludicrous amount of grip (although some pro might feel is a bit of an energy waste). :)

--> I don't see why you couldn't try the same on a 29er setup.